# Trying to program how to turn wifi off on android device

Tags: android, android-wifi

Had a read through the android documentation on WifiManager and thought I understood it but when I tried to code an example I keep running into problems.

I had the following code

```
        wifiOffButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            WifiManager mWifi = (WifiManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            mWifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

    });
```

I had tried something similar to turn off sound

```
muteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            AudioManager mAudio = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mAudio.setRingerMode(0);
        }
    });
```

this works fine, but the wifi part always gives an error, was just wondering if I'm missing something obvious as I can't seem to work it out?

Comment: This should be working. On which phone/Android version are you testing this? What error do you get (please copy/paste full dump)?

Comment: I'm testing it on a dell streak its running android 2.1, sorry I'm still quite new to this, what is it you want me to copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about adding these permissions into Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, ensure you have the appropriate permissions in your manifest file.

This should help:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me :( was just checking the permissions again to see I had entered them correctly, had them inside the application tags instead of the manifest .... go sit in the corner!